# ¿Por qué no puedo crear un archivo físico en C?

Tags: c, archivo

Una vez que ejecuto el codigo, sale en la ventana de ejecucion **No se puede crear el archivo** y no me crea fisicamente el archivo.

Este es mi código para crear un archivo

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main (){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("archivo.txt","w");
    if (fp==NULL){
        printf("\nNo se puedo crear el archivo\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tenes permiso en la carpeta donde estas ejecutando_

Comment: Agrega la cabecera: `#include  <error.h>` y haz un print de `strerror(errno)` para ver cual es el problema real. Quizá tratas de crearlo  en un directorio sin permisos.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich ahora utilice la funcion que propusiste y me sale *Permission denied*. Como puedo solucionar ese error?

Comment: @gbianchi gracias por aclarar como preguntar! Y no, no tengo permiso para crear en ninguna carpeta, porque ese error me pasa sin importar en que carpeta ejecute

Comment: Ves, estabas grabando en un directorio que no tienes permisos. No sé si estas en windows o en llinux, pero para ambos casos pon el path hacia un directorio que puedas grabar como tu home o donde está tu proyecto `fopen("c:\miapp\archivo.txt","w")` .  En todo caso en  que estás  desarrollando, Visual  Studio, CodeBlocks, etc. En estos está configurado el directorio de trabajo.

Comment: Si debes tener  permiso en la carpeta donde tienes tu programa. De lo contrario como compilas.

Comment: Tengo Windows y estoy usando Visual Studio Code. Hice lo de guardar mi codigo en el directorio de Visual y ya me crea el archivo.

Comment: Lo de no tener permiso, solo me sale cuando quiero crear un archivo fisico, pero si por ejemplo, hago lectura de un archivo txt existente e imprimo en pantalla lo que esta dentro, no tengo ningun problema de compilacion

Comment: Porque para leer se necesitan otros permisos distintos a los permisos para escribir.. en general, tenes permisos para leer en cualquier lado

Comment: Entiendo. Gracias por la ayuda!!